# How to set a breakpoint where a sound plays

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, audio, breakpoints, web-inspector

I want to find out where in a webpage's source code does a sound effect play. That'd allow me to better understand the code and obtain the audio file as well. I searched in the "Sources" and "Network" tabs of the Chrome Inspector, but there are no audio files there. The sound is probably fetched by an AJAX request or generated using the HTML5 Web Audio API. How do I set a breakpoint in the Chrome Debugger to pause when a sound plays?

Comment: Do me a favor, check the network tab, click "Img" or "Media", and reload and check there.

Comment: Otherwise, maybe check to see if there's any CSS modification that happens to the "audio player" when the sound plays... You can go into the elements panel, right click the element that gets changed (if there is one), scroll down to breakpoints, and add one there (will break on any code that changes that element). Worth a try!

Comment: If all else fails... https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-audio-capture/kfokdmfpdnokpmpbjhjbcabgligoelgp?hl=en

Comment: No audio files are in the network tab.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the link to the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in Abarnett's comment:

Use a browser add-on/extension/plug-in such as [Chrome Audio Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-audio-capture/kfokdmfpdnokpmpbjhjbcabgligoelgp?hl=en) to record internal sounds in the browser.